# Referencing value in Redux store using variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an object in my redux store called 'places'.  The children of the places object are also objects, with a key that is the id for the place.

I have used mapStateToProps to make the 'places' object available in my class, and I want to reference the value for a specific place, using its key which is the place id.

I have the id for the place stored in a variable called placeId....and I want to use this to reference the object in Redux.
I want to reference the value of the key with something like `let valueForPlaceidKey = this.props.places.variableForPlaceidIdShouldGoHere`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Realized just after I posted lol....just same way as regular JS

```
this.props.places[placeID]
```